# How to move boxing into a function instead of caller side

Tags: rust, traits, boxing

I have a trait and its implementation for some structures:

```
trait Named { 
    fn name(&self) -> String; 
}

struct Americano;
impl Named for Americano {
    fn name(&self) -> String { String::from("Caffè Americano") }
}
```

I also wish to store such structures in other structures:

```
struct Menu {
    item: Box<Named>,
}
impl Menu {
    pub fn new(item: Box<Named>) -> Self {
        Menu { item: item }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly in the case when I am boxing a structure in the `main` function:

```
fn main() {
    let s = Menu::new(Box::new(Americano));
}
```

I am curious how to move boxing inside `Menu`'s function and use something like:

```
fn main() {
    let s = Menu::new(Americano);
}
```

I have tried to implement `new` as:

```
impl Menu {
    pub fn new<T: Named>(b: T) -> Self {
        Menu { item: Box::new(b) };
    }
}
```

but I received the error

```
error: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough [--explain E0310]
  --> <anon>:19:23
   |>
19 |>         Menu { item : Box::new(b) };
   |>                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'static`...
note: ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
```

Here is the [code in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2ecf685132334d21cbab8fbe967d51e3&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Answer (score 2):

In your struct:

```
struct Menu {
    item: Box<Named>,
}
```

`Box<Named>` has an implicit [lifetime bound](http://rustbyexample.com/scope/lifetime/lifetime_bounds.html) and is equivalent to `Box<Named + 'static>`. Therefore, to meet these requirements, the value passed to `Menu::set` must also be `'static`.

```
impl Menu {
    pub fn set<T: Named + 'static>(b: T) -> Self {
        Menu { item: Box::new(b) }
    }
}
```

Another option is to generalize your struct to accept any lifetime bound.

```
struct Menu<'a> {
    item: Box<Named + 'a>
}

impl<'a> Menu<'a> {
    pub fn new(item: Box<Named + 'a>) -> Self {
        Menu { item: item }
    }

    pub fn set<T: Named + 'a>(b: T) -> Self {
        Menu { item: Box::new(b) }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer explains why the compiler suggests *consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'static`...*

Comment: Thank you,
The second variant is good enough.
It is still curious, why the Rust thinks that T may not live long enough? 
I am passing the ownership (not borrow) of the value into the function and then I am boxing the value.
I can't imagine how the passed value could be destroyed?

Comment: @seb_odessa: The value you are passing ownership of may be a borrowed pointer or contain borrowed pointers. The lifetime bound helps the compiler validate that you don't move the value in such a way that it outlives its referents.